# Hosting MVC 4 Application with MySql connection on Linux server using Mono 3.2.3

Tags: linux, asp.net-mvc-4, mono, xsp4

Does anyone have hosted MVC 4 Application on Mono 3.2.3 on Linux server ?

My Server Details is as per below :

Linux server : Debian, 
Mono Version : 3.2.3, 
XSP : XSP 4

Thank you in Advance.